# grails, mongodb - multiple dbs

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, gorm-mongodb

Is it possible to create aapliaction in grails that works the way:
User login with password and login to apliaction (authentication with spring security and postgredb), then aplication geting url to mongodb database (one per user), and then I configre application to use this db (with working mongo maped domain class)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you are asking about possibility of saving data in two data stores(Mongodb and Postgredb). In Postgredb, you want to store Spring Security authentication data and other application data in Mongodb.
Yes, this is possible. My current project had similar requirements and we are using MySQL and MongoDb.

Comment: 'm afraid I have another idea. I know that is possible to connect to two databses (PostgresSQL and  Mongo), but I want to make synamic mongodb. It should look like this: user login to app with SS and PostgreSQL. If user was authenicated, I'm geting url to his DB in mongo, and then I'm using this connection for this user. (The main point is that, the single has one mongo database)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Mongo and postgre both using following line of code in dataSource.groovy

```
development {
    grails {
        mongo {
            host = "localhost"
            username = ""
            password = ""
            databaseName = "schema_name"
        }
    }

    dataSource_lookup {
        dialect = 'org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect'
        pooled = true
        driverClassName = 'org.postgresql.Driver'
        username = "postgres"
        password = "admin"
        dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/schama_name?prepareThreshold=5&socketTimeout=5400"
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I have another idea. I know that is possible to connect to two databses (PostgresSQL and  Mongo), but I want to make synamic mongodb. It should look like this: user login to app with SS and PostgreSQL. If user was authenicated, I'm geting url to his DB in mongo, and then I'm using this connection for this user. (The main point is that, the single has one mongo database)